# How to place an icon inside a circle at the start of an input field?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to place an icon inside a circle and that circle will be placed at the start of an input field like below:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using below code in `ionic`:

// in .html

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label> <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
    <ion-input clearInput type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

// in .scss

```
ion-item {
  border-radius: 23px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ion-label {
    border-radius: 23px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But i could achieve only below:

[image]

Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use `position:absolute` for the `label` icon...And use `display:flex` to the label to align the icon inside to center

<sup>*Note: I have used font-awesome here just for icon visual...*</sup>

```css
ion-item {
  position: relative;
}

ion-label {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  z-index: 9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 46px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 23px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 50px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ion-row>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label><i class="fa fa-user"></i></ion-label>
    <input clearInput type="text">
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score -2):

very simple, just give margin to ion-icon class

```
.ion-icon{
     margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
     display: block;
}
```

Adjust the margin according to the correct position of icon.